# ActiveMQ topic wildcards not working

Tags: docker, authorization, activemq-classic

I'm trying to understand how to correctly populate **authorizationEntry** entries for topics. I've read through the details on this page [Wildcard Syntax][1]

ActiveMQ 5.14.3 is running as a Docker Container

As of now I've setup the following users (cpe = client, co = server)

```
 <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
                <users>
                    <authenticationUser username="system" password="manager" groups="co,cpe,admins"/>
                    <authenticationUser username="wbhms" password="password" groups="co"/>
                    <authenticationUser username="kpi" password="password" groups="co"/>
                    <authenticationUser username="cpeuser" password="password" groups="cpe"/>
                </users>
            </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
```

My **authorizationPlugin** is defined as follows to decide who can read and write to each topic.

The topics are all prefixed with a string identifying the client device. So for device **000295-0123456789** on topic **kpi.lte.gzipjson** the full topic name would be **000295-0123456789.kpi.lte.gzipjson**.

So my thought was to prefix the topic attribute with a * as you can see below to account for all devices.

```
    <authorizationPlugin>
        <map>
            <authorizationMap>
                <authorizationEntries>
                    <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins,co,cpe" write="admins,co,cpe" admin="admins,co,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.will.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.lte.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.lte.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.bt.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.bt.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.ble.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.ble.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.wifi.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.wifi.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.lte.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.lte.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.bt.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.bt.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.ble.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.ble.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.wifi.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.wifi.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.scans.wifi.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.scans.wifi.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.tasks.gzipjson>" read="cpe" write="co" admin="admins,co"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.tasks.json>" read="cpe" write="co" admin="admins,co"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.acks.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,co"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.acks.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.messages.gzipjson>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.messages.json>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="admins,co,cpe" write="admins,co,cpe" admin="admins,co,cpe"/>
                </authorizationEntries>
            </authorizationMap>
        </map>
    </authorizationPlugin>
```

However, when my server and clients try to subscribe exceptions are thrown for all the topics. Here is one of the many errors I am seeing in the logs.

```
 WARN | Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://11.157.3.9:48396, User wbhms is not authorized to read from: topic://*.will.gzipjson
 WARN | Error subscribing to +/will/gzipjson
java.lang.SecurityException: User wbhms is not authorized to read from: topic://*.will.gzipjson
        at org.apache.activemq.security.AuthorizationBroker.addConsumer(AuthorizationBroker.java:159)[activemq-broker-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConsumer(MutableBrokerFilter.java:108)[activemq-broker-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConsumer(TransportConnection.java:706)[activemq-broker-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo.visit(ConsumerInfo.java:351)[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:336)[activemq-broker-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)[activemq-broker-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:45)[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTInactivityMonitor.onCommand(MQTTInactivityMonitor.java:162)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTTransportFilter.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTTransportFilter.java:106)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:181)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.strategy.AbstractMQTTSubscriptionStrategy.doSubscribe(AbstractMQTTSubscriptionStrategy.java:210)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.strategy.MQTTDefaultSubscriptionStrategy.onSubscribe(MQTTDefaultSubscriptionStrategy.java:72)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.strategy.AbstractMQTTSubscriptionStrategy.onSubscribe(AbstractMQTTSubscriptionStrategy.java:118)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onSubscribe(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:387)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTCommand(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:213)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTTransportFilter.onCommand(MQTTTransportFilter.java:94)[activemq-mqtt-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
```

If I modify the first entry as follows I'm able to write and read from the topics

```
<authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins,co,cpe" write="admins,co,cpe" admin="admins,co,cpe"/>
```

Comment: have you tried  <authorizationEntry topic="*.will.gzipjson.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="admins"/>

Comment: i think that this is not possible "*.messages.json>" but this yes "*.messages.json.>"   ,

* is used to match any name in a path
> is used to recursively match any destination starting from this name

Comment: @HassenBennour That helped me solve the issue. Also I combined a few topics into one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @HassenBennour I was able to find a solution. All is good in the world.

My working set of entries is as follows

```
                <authorizationEntries>
                    <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.will.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.kpi.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.sightings.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.scans.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.tasks.>" read="cpe" write="co" admin="co,cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.acks.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.messages.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="*.errors.>" read="co" write="cpe" admin="cpe"/>
                    <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="admins,co,cpe" write="admins,co,cpe" admin="admins,co,cpe"/>
                </authorizationEntries>
```